# How can I set auto-slider function into this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a slider for my website and It only works when I click `.slideshow-prev` or `.slideshow-next`. I want to set this function automatically without clicking the `prev` or `next` button.

```
   <script>
    //an image width in pixels
    var imageWidth = 980;


    //DOM and all content is loaded
    $(window).ready(function() {

      var currentImage = 0;

      //set image count
      var allImages = $('#slideshow li img').length;

      //setup slideshow frame width
      $('#slideshow ul').width(allImages * imageWidth);

      //attach click event to slideshow buttons
      $('.slideshow-next').click(function() {

        //increase image counter
        currentImage++;
        //if we are at the end let set it to 0
        if (currentImage >= allImages) currentImage = 0;
        //calcualte and set position
        setFramePosition(currentImage);

      });

      $('.slideshow-prev').click(function() {

        //decrease image counter
        currentImage--;
        //if we are at the end let set it to 0
        if (currentImage < 0) currentImage = allImages - 1;
        //calcualte and set position
        setFramePosition(currentImage);

      });

    });

    //calculate the slideshow frame position and animate it to the new position
    function setFramePosition(pos) {

      //calculate position
      var px = imageWidth * pos * -1;
      //set ul left position
      $('#slideshow ul').animate({
        left: px
      }, 300);
    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your images to always be changed to the next one in a 2 seconds interval:

```
setInterval(function() {
    //increase image counter
    currentImage++;
    //if we are at the end let set it to 0
    if (currentImage >= allImages) currentImage = 0;
    //calculate and set position
    setFramePosition(currentImage);
}, 2000);
```

[More about Javascript's setInterval.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you would just need to use an interval timer. Set a variable near the top of your script to hold this.

```
//DOM and all content is loaded
$(window).ready(function() {

  var currentImage = 0;
  var rotator;
```

and then assign the timer in a function, I did this near the bottom of your script:

```
//calculate the slideshow frame position and animate it to the new position
function setFramePosition(pos) {

  //calculate position
  var px = imageWidth * pos * -1;
  //set ul left position
  $('#slideshow ul').animate({
    left: px
  }, 300);
}

function startRotator(){
    //store it in a variable so you can clear it later if needed
    rotator = setInterval(function(){

        currentImage++;

        //it is generally a good idea to wrap even single-line conditionals in brackets to help with clarity. especially if another dev starts using your code
        if (currentImage >= allImages){ 
            currentImage = 0; 
        }
        setFramePosition(currentImage);

    }, 5000); //5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
}

startRotator(); //start it up
```

So that should take care of the timer, however this will run independently of any kind of user interaction. So, if a user starts clicking the next or previous buttons, this timer is still going to continue rotating slides too. That won't be good, so we need to reset the timer during those events. Make some modifications to your slideshow-next and prev events

```
 //attach click event to slideshow buttons
  $('.slideshow-next').click(function() {

    //if rotator exists, clear it
    if(typeof rotator != 'undefined'){
        clearInterval(rotator);
    }

    //increase image counter
    currentImage++;
    //if we are at the end let set it to 0
    if (currentImage >= allImages) currentImage = 0;
    //calcualte and set position
    setFramePosition(currentImage);

    //start the rotator back up again
    startRotator();

  });
```

I will leave you to modify the slideshow-prev one, but it should look pretty much the same.